# Next.js cookies on the Server Side

Tags: authentication, cookies, jwt, next.js

so I've been trying to learn JWT and so far I've created a simple Express API for that and a simple Next.js app with functionalities like Login and a page that's only available if the user has a valid access token.

Right now I'm stuck on an issue and I can't find any solution for it - while normal tokens are quite easy to understand I read that I'm going to need refresh tokens of sort, used when normal access token expires (and these expire quite frequently). On the backend I can validate both tokens and I send a new, valid token if it has already expired.

## Current flow of the app:

When I'm on the client side and I click a button that redirects me to the protected page it works like this:

- If the user has a token and it's valid - Redirect to /route
- If the user has an invalid token and has an invalid refresh token, redirect to /login
- If the user has an invalid token and has a valid refresh token, redirect to /route and send a new token, set the new token in Cookies

(If the logic is incorrect, please correct me on that, too).
So far so good - this part works correctly.

Now on the server side what should happen if the user's token has expired and user has a valid refresh token? I can send the token back to the Next.js app, but I'm still on the server side and I can not update the cookie. The redirect part works fine. Should I even update the cookie or should it update itself when user makes a client-side action, like going to another protected page?

Thank you!

Comment: Read https://blog.hasura.io/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/

Comment: Why not just do all the token refresh stuff on the frontend instead of on the server? Also, you can set cookies from the server by sending cookie headers in the response.

Comment: Frontend refreshing works fine, I just though it would be okay to also refresh them when the user opens the /route page directly from the browser (so the server handles it first), but I see that i just should allow the user into the page if the refresh token is valid and then update the access token when the user performs an action on the FE.